# Amplified input gets offset?

Tags: operational-amplifier

I'm not very good at this but my question is: why does the output waveform get offset by ~0.4V when passed through the op-amp (LM386)? It is initially a sine wave with no DC offset, 1Hz frequency, and 0.1V amplitude.[image: Here is my circuit and graph, I am simulating using LTSpice.]

[image]

After adding the load resistor as Andy said, I get the graph I want. However, now I want to pass that output signal through a diode bridge to rectify it. Am I doing something wrong? How come it gets offset again and the rectified graph isn't actually rectified? [image]

[image]

Comment: You haven't got any sign or hint of a load resistor on the capacitor output therefore any DC voltage offset is possible.

Comment: thank you! I have another question if you don't mind. I edited my post

Comment: LM386 is not an op-amp.

Answer (score 0):

You're clamping your output to ground with the bridge rectifier.  The cap charges disproportionately when the output is below ground, through D1 and D3.  Depending on your load, that could be the rectification you want...are you measuring the level, or trying to drive a motor?

Another option is to use a [precision rectifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_rectifier).

Comment: Where should I ground it then? I only want the rectified signal to start from 0V and use a transistor afterwards to give a signal when a certain voltage has been reached

Comment: And what is that voltage?

Comment: Idk, I guess it can be any value. Let's say 1V?

Comment: It's easier if it's over 1.4V.  Leave D1 in, remove D2, D3, & D4. Low pass the offset sine wave (or peak detect it) and use an NPN transistor--that gives you 0.7V offset from the clamp, and an additional 0.7V to turn on the transistor.  If you want a higher threshold, use a pot as a voltage divider to adjust it.